# How to find and list all apps/packages in Windows (both installed, and install.wim)

Tags: windows-10

How to find and list all apps/packages in Windows (both installed, and `install.wim`)?

I'd like to remove the bloatware apps from 1909 install image, but I don't know exactly what I can remove.

MSMG has a list which is incomplete, but contains entries of packages I didn't know from simple PowerShell command (e.g. `UnifiedTelemetryClient`, or even `AdobeFlashForWindows`).

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about this One-Liner, @Haunter?

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\dobre> Get-ItemProperty HKLM:Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Sort-Object -Property @{Expression={$_.Publisher}; Ascending = $True}| Format-Table -AutoSize

DisplayName                                DisplayVersion   Publisher                   InstallDate
-----------                                --------------   ---------                   -----------


ASUS Smart Gesture                         4.0.18           ASUS                        20191007
ASUS Splendid Video Enhancement Technology 3.13.0004        ASUS                        20191011
ASUS Live Update                           3.6.8            ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.       20191011
Auslogics Duplicate File Finder            8.2.0.1          Auslogics Labs Pty Ltd      20191106
Foxit Reader                               9.7.0.29455      Foxit Software Inc.         20191030
Google Update Helper                       1.3.35.341       Google LLC                  20191105
Google Chrome                              78.0.3904.97     Google LLC                  20191108
Intel(R) Processor Graphics                10.18.10.4425    Intel Corporation
DriverToolkit version 8.5.0.0              8.5.0.0          Megaify Software            20191011
Microsoft OneDrive                         19.192.0926.0011 Microsoft Corporation
Realtek High Definition Audio Driver       6.0.1.8186       Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Norton Utilities                           16.0.3.44        Symantec Corporation        20191014
TeamViewer 14                              14.6.4835        TeamViewer
ViewRight Web PC 3.6.0.0                   3.6.0.0          Verimatrix, Inc.            20191021


PS C:\Users\dobre>
```

Reluctantly, we have removed the nice, flashy and brighty colors, fonts and graphics as advised by @Kamil Maciorowski.

***Edit***: Following @Robert's comment, we have added another One-Liner that might complete our quest. What do you think about this one?

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-appxprovisionedpackage -online|grep -i DisplayName;Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers|grep -i "^Name"
DisplayName  : Microsoft.BingWeather
DisplayName  : Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller
DisplayName  : Microsoft.GetHelp
DisplayName  : Microsoft.Getstarted
DisplayName  : Microsoft.HEIFImageExtension
DisplayName  : Microsoft.Messaging
DisplayName  : Microsoft.Microsoft3DViewer
DisplayName  : Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub
DisplayName  : Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection
DisplayName  : Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes
DisplayName  : Microsoft.MixedReality.Portal
DisplayName  : Microsoft.MSPaint
DisplayName  : Microsoft.Office.OneNote
DisplayName  : Microsoft.OneConnect
DisplayName  : Microsoft.People
DisplayName  : Microsoft.Print3D
DisplayName  : Microsoft.ScreenSketch
DisplayName  : Microsoft.SkypeApp
DisplayName  : Microsoft.StorePurchaseApp
DisplayName  : Microsoft.VP9VideoExtensions
DisplayName  : Microsoft.Wallet
DisplayName  : Microsoft.WebMediaExtensions
DisplayName  : Microsoft.WebpImageExtension
DisplayName  : Microsoft.Windows.Photos
DisplayName  : Microsoft.WindowsAlarms
DisplayName  : Microsoft.WindowsCalculator
DisplayName  : Microsoft.WindowsCamera
DisplayName  : microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps
DisplayName  : Microsoft.WindowsFeedbackHub
DisplayName  : Microsoft.WindowsMaps
DisplayName  : Microsoft.WindowsSoundRecorder
DisplayName  : Microsoft.WindowsStore
DisplayName  : Microsoft.Xbox.TCUI
DisplayName  : Microsoft.XboxApp
DisplayName  : Microsoft.XboxGameOverlay
DisplayName  : Microsoft.XboxGamingOverlay
DisplayName  : Microsoft.XboxIdentityProvider
DisplayName  : Microsoft.XboxSpeechToTextOverlay
DisplayName  : Microsoft.YourPhone
DisplayName  : Microsoft.ZuneMusic
DisplayName  : Microsoft.ZuneVideo
Name                   : Microsoft.PPIProjection
Name                   : windows.immersivecontrolpanel
Name                   : Windows.PrintDialog
Name                   : Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.7
Name                   : Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.0
Name                   : Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.7
Name                   : Microsoft.Wallet
Name                   : Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00
Name                   : Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00
Name                   : Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.7
Name                   : Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.7
Name                   : Microsoft.Xbox.TCUI
Name                   : Microsoft.ZuneVideo
Name                   : Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.2
Name                   : Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.2
Name                   : Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.2.2
Name                   : Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.1
Name                   : Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.2.2
Name                   : Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.1
Name                   : Microsoft.Windows.Photos
Name                   : Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.0
Name                   : Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop
Name                   : Microsoft.Messaging
Name                   : Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop
Name                   : Microsoft.ScreenSketch
Name                   : Microsoft.WindowsCamera
Name                   : Microsoft.ZuneMusic
Name                   : Microsoft.WindowsSoundRecorder
Name                   : Microsoft.MSPaint
Name                   : Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub
Name                   : Microsoft.Print3D
Name                   : Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.1
Name                   : Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.2.1
Name                   : Microsoft.Advertising.Xaml
Name                   : Microsoft.Advertising.Xaml
Name                   : Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.2.1
Name                   : Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.2.1
Name                   : Microsoft.BingWeather
Name                   : Microsoft.XboxApp
Name                   : Microsoft.Office.OneNote
Name                   : microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps
Name                   : Microsoft.Getstarted
Name                   : Microsoft.XboxSpeechToTextOverlay
Name                   : Microsoft.Services.Store.Engagement
Name                   : Microsoft.Services.Store.Engagement
Name                   : Microsoft.WebMediaExtensions
Name                   : Microsoft.Microsoft3DViewer
Name                   : Microsoft.XboxIdentityProvider
Name                   : Microsoft.OneConnect
Name                   : Microsoft.WindowsFeedbackHub
Name                   : Microsoft.MixedReality.Portal
Name                   : Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.2
Name                   : Microsoft.UI.Xaml.2.2
Name                   : Microsoft.WindowsCalculator
Name                   : Microsoft.Windows.Cortana
Name                   : Microsoft.PPIProjection
Name                   : Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection
Name                   : Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes
Name                   : InputApp
Name                   : Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin
Name                   : Microsoft.AccountsControl
Name                   : Microsoft.AsyncTextService
Name                   : Microsoft.BioEnrollment
Name                   : Microsoft.CredDialogHost
Name                   : Microsoft.ECApp
Name                   : Microsoft.LockApp
Name                   : Microsoft.MicrosoftEdgeDevToolsClient
Name                   : Microsoft.PPIProjection
Name                   : Microsoft.Windows.Apprep.ChxApp
Name                   : Microsoft.Windows.CallingShellApp
Name                   : Microsoft.Windows.CapturePicker
Name                   : Microsoft.Windows.OOBENetworkCaptivePortal
Name                   : Microsoft.Windows.OOBENetworkConnectionFlow
Name                   : Microsoft.Windows.ParentalControls
Name                   : Microsoft.Windows.PinningConfirmationDialog
Name                   : Microsoft.XboxGameCallableUI
Name                   : 1527c705-839a-4832-9118-54d4Bd6a0c89
Name                   : c5e2524a-ea46-4f67-841f-6a9465d9d515
Name                   : E2A4F912-2574-4A75-9BB0-0D023378592B
Name                   : F46D4000-FD22-4DB4-AC8E-4E1DDDE828FE
Name                   : Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge
Name                   : Microsoft.Win32WebViewHost
Name                   : Microsoft.Windows.CloudExperienceHost
Name                   : Microsoft.Windows.ContentDeliveryManager
Name                   : Microsoft.Windows.NarratorQuickStart
Name                   : Microsoft.Windows.PeopleExperienceHost
Name                   : Microsoft.Windows.SecHealthUI
Name                   : Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost
Name                   : Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost
Name                   : Microsoft.Windows.XGpuEjectDialog
Name                   : Windows.CBSPreview
Name                   : Microsoft.WindowsMaps
Name                   : Microsoft.WindowsAlarms
Name                   : Microsoft.People
Name                   : Microsoft.GetHelp
Name                   : Microsoft.XboxGamingOverlay
Name                   : 9E2F88E3.Twitter
Name                   : Microsoft.VP9VideoExtensions
Name                   : Microsoft.HEIFImageExtension
Name                   : Microsoft.WebpImageExtension
Name                   : Microsoft.XboxGameOverlay
Name                   : Microsoft.YourPhone
Name                   : Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller
Name                   : Microsoft.StorePurchaseApp
Name                   : Microsoft.WindowsStore
Name                   : Microsoft.SkypeApp
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: It only shows installed programs not apps. And I assume the more interesting part of the question was on the apps in `install.wim`.